# How to organize this context? Two tables or just one?

Tags: php, database, laravel, database-design, eloquent

I have a context of registrations at conferences. A registration has only one step if is a free registration. If is a paid registration there are two steps.

The first step of the registration consists of the user fill in a registration form and after click in the "Store Registration" button the info is stored in database and the column "status" of the registratins table is stored always with value "I" (incomplete).

If is a free registration there are no additional steps.

But if its a paid registration there is another step. In this step 2 the user needs to pay the registration before the conference start date. After the payment of the registration the column "status" of the registrations table stays with value "C" (complete).

**Doubt:**

If is a paid registration, after the step1 is necessary to issue a proforma invoice to the user and after the step2, that is, after the payment is necessary to issue a invoice/receipt to the user.

My doubt is  how to organize the database for this context of issue proformas and invoices. In each paid registration is necessary to issue first a proforma after the user click in the "Store registration" button and all registration info is stored in db and then an issue an invoice after the payment. Is necessary to have two models/tables "Invoices" and "Proformas" and each one has a 1 to 1 relationship with Registration table. Or its just necessary 1 table related to the Registration table?

For now, I created two tables Proforma and Invoice and the relationships of these tables with the Registration table is like below 1 to 1, but I dont know if its correct.

**Tables structure:**

```
registration columns: id, status, conference_id, user_that_did_registration
proformas: id, proforma_number, registration_id
invoices: id, invoice_number, registration_id
```

**Relevant models for the question:**

Registration Model:

```
class Registration extends Model
{
    public function customer(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_that_did_registration', 'id');
    }

    public function participants(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Participant');
    }

    public function registration_types(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\RegistrationType', 'registration_registration_types');
    }

    public function conference(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\conference');
    }

    public function proforma()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Proforma');
    }

    public function invoice()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Invoice');
    }
}
```

Proforma model:

```
class Proforma extends Model
{
    public function registration()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Registration');
    }
}
```

Invoice model:

```
class Invoice extends Model
{
    public function registration()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Registration');
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you researched database design in the past?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, your design looks pretty close.  Since not all Registrations have Proformas or Invoices, it makes sense to have Proformas and Invoices in a separate table.  I would only make one change - if the relationship between Proformas and Invoices is truly 1 to 1, then you can put all the fields in a single record:

```
Proformas
    ID
    Registration_ID
    Proforma_Number
    Invoice_Number
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is no relationship between proforma and invoice, there is a relationship between 1-1 between Registrations and Proformas and there is a 1-1 between Registrations and Invoices.

Comment: If it's possible to have an Invoice on a Registration without a corresponding Proforma, then the design you worked out is fine.  From your description, I got the impression that the Invoice was logically linked to the Proforma on a paid registration.

Comment: Thanks, after a user did a registration in a paid conference is generated always a proforma for the user. But only if the user complete the step 2 of a paid registration, that consists in the payment of the registration, the invoice is generated. But so a invoice is not always generated because the user can do the registration, receive the proforma but then dont complete the registration (dont pay) and no invoice is sent to the user and the registration is canceled.